# Google (Firebase) Authentication in Ionic

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I have created an Ionic app with Firebase integration. I'm using Google Authentication to sign in to Firebase and retrieve things like the user's Friends, ect.

```
public signInWithPopup() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => { // code })
}
```

This works perfect when testing in browser with 'ionic serve'. The sign in method opens a popup, I enter my Google Credentials, I press 'sign in' and the popup closes and I'm signed in in my app.

When I deploy the app to my iOS device (ionic cordova run ios) the same popup is opened (in iOS safari), I can still enter my credentials, but when I press 'sign in' Google displays an error page: "400. That’s an error. The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know."

What is happening here, what do I do wrong?

I'm guessing it might have something to do that it tries to redirect to the app, which might be an url in my browser, when testing on my laptop, but there is no such thing in my Ionic app since it is an app and not a webpage?

Comment: Have you followed the documentation on the Firebase site, and configured everything properly for iOS?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

Comment: For Ionic/Cordova, you should use signInWithRedirect. Check the docs for more on this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova